# Matlab data Interpolation from unstructured 2D grid to a coarse structured 2D grid

Tags: matlab, grid, interpolation

I work with Matlab, and I have a 2D fine unstructured grid (x,y - 900000 x 1, 900000 x1) with a 1D array of (temperature) values (900000 x 1) for each node of the unstructured grid!

I have create a coarse structured 2D grid and I am trying to find a way to interpolate my data to this new grid. 
Please, does anyone know or could suggest a way to do that?

any suggestion/help is more than welcome!

Thank you,

G.

Comment: Look for `griddata`.

Comment: Thanks Cris, but griddata cant work. The data are in 1D, NOT in a grid (x,y), and the reason is that this is a big file: 90000 by 1

Comment: You have 900k points, for each point there is a `x` and `y` coordinate, and a value `v`. You want to resample these values onto a regular grid given by `xq` and `yq`. `griddata(x,y,v,xq,yq)` does this. Read the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/griddata.html).

Comment: Chris, thank you! it works! I use the next format: griddata(x,y,v,xq,yq.')

Comment: Chris please explain me something I cant understand.C = griddata(x,y,v,xq,yq), is a 2D array in xq by yq. Can I convert the C to 1D array in case the structure grid is unstructured grid? I need this C to be like the original one... make sense?

Comment: I've posted an answer for your original question and this new question. Let me know if something is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have a set of points defined by coordinates in `x` and `y`, and corresponding temperature values in `t`, such that the temperature at (`x(i)`,`y(i)`) is `t(i)`. There is no structure to the locations for each point.

You want to find the temperatures at new locations given by `xq`, `yq`. These can either form a grid or be unstructured. Let's define a grid:

```
[xq, yq] = meshgrid(linspace(0,1,100), linspace(-0.5,0.5,100));
```

In this example grid, we have 100 samples between 0 and 1 along the x-axis, and 100 samples between -0.5 and 0.5 along the y-axis, for a total of 10k points.

The function [`griddata`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/griddata.html) will interpolate in the input data on the new locations:

```
tq = griddata(x,y,t, xq,yq);
```

`tq` now has the same shape as `xq` and `yq`, that is, it is a 100x100 matrix. To turn this into a new list like the original, simply reshape it to a vector. `tq = tq(:)` does this. Alternatively, reshape the query location arrays before calling `griddata`:

```
xq = xq(:);
yq = yq(:);
tq = griddata(x,y,t, xq,yq);
```

Now `tq` is a column vector.

Comment: Thank so much Cris!!!! ... I was working all day trying to solve that. I never used list data in 2D; that was confusing me, but it seems that it is crucial for big data. Thank you!